# Don't understand where my "Unnecessary escape character" error comes from

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, eslint, regex-recursion

I have a url that contains two values, a keyword and a location name. The keyword comes after the '/r/' and the location after the '/l/'. 
**E.g: localhost:3000/search/r/keyword/l/location**

To get only the value after the '/r/' (keyword) and the value after the '/l/' (location); I'm doing the following Regexr:

```
var cutResult = window.location.href.match(/\br\/\b(\b[^\/]+\b)/gi);
var cutLocation = window.location.href.match(/\b\/l\/\b(\b[^\/]+\b)/gi);
```

This does the trick, however, React returns following message:

> Unnecessary escape character: /  no-useless-escape

What causes the error?

Comment: It is unnecessary to escape `/` inside a `[...]` character class. So just `[^/]+` will do. Also you seem to have a few too many `\b`s...

Comment: The [^/]+ did the trick. However I don't know about the \b; I used a [regexr generator](https://regexr.com/) to understand and create the above expression.

Comment: Well personally I wouldn't use regex for this, I'd `.split("/")` and then scan through the pieces to find `r` or `l` and mark the next item as that value.

Comment: Interesting; will try this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to escape most of the characters inside a character class (inside [...]) only a few:

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters
>   inside a character class are the closing bracket ], the backslash \,
>   the caret ^, and the hyphen -. The usual metacharacters are normal
>   characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by
>   a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will
>   work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character
>   class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.